# Prayers from Shacharit liturgy that should be said daily even if Shacharit is missed

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, mistakes

If I miss Shacharit, which prayers from the Shacharit liturgy should I be sure to still say (even if I have to say them later in the day)? I know I should say an extra Amida during Mincha if I missed it by mistake, but in any case what other prayers should I still be sure to say every day even if it's late in the day?